# Когда я использую a.check(); приложение вылетает из-за чего это может быть? (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
a.check(); 
находится в классе Q.
вызывается класс так 
Q a = new Q();
```

MainActivity

```
package dima113xxx.scr;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Q a = new Q();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      a.check();


    }

}
```

public class Q extends AppCompatActivity

```
package dima113xxx.scr;

import android.Manifest;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;



import static android.R.attr.permission;

public class Q extends AppCompatActivity {
   public static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    public static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };


    public void check() {


        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }else
        { }

    }

}
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас `NPE` на строке

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, //тут this - null
```

Это происходит потому что вы неправильно используете активити. Их нельзя создавать вручную через конструктор, т.к. экземпляры этих классов создаются системой. Если вы хотите из одной активити запустить другую, то вам надо:

1. Прописать целевую актиивти в манифесте (аналогично с уже имеющейся там `MainActivity`)
2. Запустить интент, согласно которому система запустит новую активити. Делается это так: `startActivity(new Intent(this, Q.class));`

И да, вы не можете явно управлять из одной активити другой. Андроид так не работает.